# Django-import-export with Django admin, how to add new file format

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm using Django-Admin to import/export data with Django-import-export package, every thing is OK with Json, csv... but I realy can't find how to import ".dbf" files via Django admin app.
Can someone help me! Thinks

Comment: What versions of Django and django-import-export are you using? Are you able to provide a MWE (minimum working example) so that we can see what you have done?